# What's wrong with my connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET MVC application, but have been struggling all day to even get a model from the database set up. The frustrating part is that the connection string was generated when I created the ADO.NET model from the database, and it doesn't like it.

The connection strings found in **web.config**:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     />
<add name="DatabaseEntities" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DatabaseModels.csdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModels.ssdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
   />
```

Exception triggered at statement:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString))
{..}
```

'ArgumentException' Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

**SOLUTION:**
As LTMOD answered, I needed two connections in web.config, the initial SqlClient and the generated EntityClient connection. I needed to use the SqlClient connection string in the 'using' statement, as well as calling con.Open() in the block.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string for entities and ADO is somewhat different.  In my projects, I typically have both.  Something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USER;Password=PWD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PTModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PTModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PTModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DBNAME;user id=USER;password=PWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

DefaultConnection is used by ADO, while Entity access automatically uses the Entities connection.

There are a number of reason for this. For one thing, sometimes it's easier to construct an SQL query to perform a task rather than jumping through hoops with LINQ/Lambda.  There are plenty of cases where all of the work needs to take place in the DB, and having both connections lets you easily do this.

Comment: I was being a bit dense earlier and hadn't changed the SqlConnection argument to the default connection's string. There is now a new exception ServerVersion = 'con.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException', as I think the default connection string is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

- You used `DatabaseEntities` for your `ADO.net` access layer, that
  connection is meant for Entity framework.
- No you don't need 2 connection strings for `ADO.net`, you will need
  them only for EF when using `EDMX` files because they need `DefaultConnection` in addition to the model connection string (`DatabaseEntities`).
- Use `DefaultConnection` and if you still get errors, it means your connection string is not correct, use visual studio to connect to your database and copy the connections string to your web.config file.

```
var connectionString = 
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString){...}
```